# How do you enable "dark mode" for the AutoHotKey GUI windows?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, dark-mode

I use AutoHotKey to pop up little boxes where I can paste various things into and then press Enter to forward this to my more advanced scripts.

They look way too bright when I've made such great efforts to make all other applications and Windows 10 use "dark mode".

I can't figure out how to make the AutoHotKey GUI windows use "dark mode". Is it even possible?

I don't mean specifying a manual dark background. I mean something "native", if possible.

Version 1.1.33.10.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what your Color settings are exactly?  Of course application must also support Windows Dark mode, many applications do not, AutoHotKey might be one of those applications.  However, without knowing your Windows settings, it's impossible to formulate a quality answer.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't understand why my exact settings would matter. I have dark mode enabled in Windows 10 and in every application that supports it. I now want it for AutoHotKey GUI boxes too.

Comment: Because you can have Windows in Dark mode but have the default application be Light mode.  Which is the entire reason I want to see what your current settings are.  So can you please, [edit] your question, to include this vital piece of information?

Comment: @Ramhound I genuinely don't understand what you're talking about.

Comment: Is the problem with the GUI command or with MsgBox?

Comment: @harrymc Well, the background is bright grey and the form elements are all brights, so clearly it's using the "light" or "classic" mode. Possibly it's even hardcoded/custom in AutoHotKey. I guess "Gui", because I have many instances of "Gui" in my script, but no "MsgBox".

Answer (score 1):

When using the
[GUI command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm),
add the following sub-commands before doing the final
[Gui, Show](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Show)
command that displays the dialog:

- [Gui, Color](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Color) :
  Sets the background color of the window and/or its controls
- [Gui, Font](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Font) :
  Sets the font typeface, size, style, and/or color.

Comment: Well, this leaves an ugly white border around the GUI element(s) and it just doesn't look right at all. Which is why I mentioned that I don't want to just change the colours manually. :/

Comment: Could you include in your post the AHK script that you use? Does [Gui, Margin](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Margin) help?